# CSS3 Navigation Bar: Float:Right

Tags: html, css, css-float, navbar

I'm creating and designing a mini social networking website for our school's Science Fair, and I already have a problem at the designing stage. :(

So I've created a few PSDs on how my website *should* look like, but it seems harder to translate my designs into HTML/CSS. My current trouble right now is this navigation bar that isn't cooperating with me...

In short, this navigation bar is very simple; the logo, with the title, a subtitle, and a few menu options (Login, Sign up). I'm using `float:right;` to float my options to the right, but that isn't working very well.

The options of my navigation bar are jutting out, below the Navigation Bar. It's really odd; when I take out the `float:right;` it seems perfectly fine, but is to the left. I would really like it to be on the right side.

A sample of the website is available at http://ticktalk.me.pn/. A PSD of the Sign-Up Page is available here: http://img1.imagilive.com/0314/tickTalk-signup.jpg.

Please feel free to "View Page Source" and investigate what I've done wrong. A direct link to the css is available at http://ticktalk.me.pn/css/style.css.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

This is my Navigation Bar HTML...

```
<div class= "navbar-header">
    <div class= "navbar-title"><a href= "#">
        tick<span class= "bookfont">talk</span>
    </a></div>
    <div class= "navbar-subtitle">
        social networking around the clock
    </div>
    <div class= "navbar-menu">
        <div class= "navbar-option login-button">
            Login
        </div>
        <div class= "navbar-option navbar-checked signup-button">
            Sign Up
        </div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
.navbar-header {
    display:block;
    background-color: rgb(0, 241, 73);
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:75px;
}
.navbar-logo {
    display:inline-block;
}
.navbar-title {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 52px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:5px;
}
.bookfont {
    font-weight: 500;
}
.navbar-subtitle {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.navbar-menu {
    float:right;
}
.navbar-option {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:25px;
    padding:20px;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right:30px;
}
.navbar-checked {
    background-color: rgb(0, 217, 63);
}
```

Comment: Post your code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the element with that has "float: right" before the rest of the elements on that line.

Basically, move `<div class="navbar-menu">...</div>` before `<img src="logo.png" ...>`.
Or, in the sample code of the edited question, move `<div class="navbar-menu">...</div>` before `<div class="navbar-title">...</div>`.

I am not sure regarding the technical justification to this, but floats are better put before the non floats.
Perhaps this is because it assumes there is no room for the floating element.

Comment: Well, the options were moved to the side (yay), but now the rest of the navbar has shifted to the right. :(

Comment: @JaredCubilla - What browser are you using? when I did it to the URL you posted, it fixed the issue completely in Chrome. I have not tested other browsers.

Comment: Oops, sorry, just a misunderstanding of your post. Works perfectly! YOU ARE A LIFESAVER!

Answer (score 1):

Try *elements on the left side* wrapping with another `div`. Like this for example:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <div class="another-div">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo.png" class="navbar-logo" width="47" height="47">
        <div class="navbar-title">
           <a href="#">tick<span class="bookfont">talk</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-subtitle">
            social networking around the clock
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu">
        <div class="navbar-option login-button">
            Login
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-option navbar-checked signup-button">
            Sign Up
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then give that `.another-div` CSS property `float:left`, and don't forget to set a `hight` for the `.navbar-header` after this.

```
.another-div{
    float: left;
}
.navbar-header{
    height: 80px;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Using `float: ...` (or more of it) is discouraged, especially when it is not needed. It complicates the structure and it hurts the performance of the web.

Comment: @PhistucK can I have a source of this point please? Or may be you have invented a new W3 rule? It is very funny if you talk about performance, when it comes to a simple css property. :)

Comment: `opacity` is also a simple CSS property that can hurt performance, it creates a new stacking context. I know Chrome (or its renderer) can be hung when you browse to pages that use many, many floats.

Comment: Works nicely, but I would really prefer if the _options_ were placed to the right.

Comment: @PhistucK. well, do we care about `opacity` for OP's question? Remember, `float` doesn't hurt the performance in any way. Your point is invalid.

Comment: I was responding to "It is very funny if you talk about performance, when it comes to a simple css property", of course it is unrelated to the question, it is related to your comment. Some properties, even 'simple' or most used once, have higher performance costs than others. I do not have a link at hand right now, but I might search and get back to you later on that.